# Conversion of MongoDB3.0 query to java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

I am working on java and MongoDb 3.0 and having one query which I want to convert into java code.

Mongo DB query is as below:

```
db.users.find({ $or: [ { updated_at:{ $gt:90, $lte:200}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:350, $lte:400}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:560, $lte:700}} ] })
```

Java Query for this would be like below.

```
List<Document> orqueryList = new ArrayList<Document>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("90:200");
    list1.add("350:400");
    list1.add("560:700");

    Document greaterQuery = new Document();
    Document lessQuery = new Document();
    Document lEQuery = new Document();
    Document gEQuery = new Document();

    for (String time : list1) {

        String[] updatedAtt = tim.split(":");


        gEQuery.put("$gte", Long.parseLong(updatedAtt[0]));
        lEQuery.put("$lte", Long.parseLong(updatedAtt[1]));


        greaterQuery.put("updated_at", gEQuery);
        lessQuery.put("updated_at", lEQuery);
            orqueryList.add(greaterQuery);
          orqueryList.add(lessQuery);

        }
    query.put("$or", orqueryList);
```

But this is not working as my `orqueryList` list giving me size 3 with last values as below

> [Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$gte=560}}}},
>   Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$lte=700}}}},
>   Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$gte=560}}}},
>   Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$lte=700}}}},
>   Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$gte=560}}}},
>   Document{{received_at_server=Document{{$lte=700}}}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.users.find({ $or: [ { updated_at:{ $gt:90, $lte:200}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:350, $lte:400}}, { updated_at:{ $gt:560, $lte:700}} ] })
```

The query has two parts - 
1. AND operation for updated_at value $gt and $lte
2. OR operation for list of above AND operation.

```
    greaterQuery.put("updated_at", gEQuery);
    lessQuery.put("updated_at", lEQuery);
    orqueryList.add(greaterQuery);
    orqueryList.add(lessQuery);

  }
  query.put("$or", orqueryList);
```

Your above java code checks only for OR condition (the list orqueryList). You are adding the $gt and $lte condition to the OR condition itself.

Try the below logic:

```
Document query = new Document();
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Document> andQueryList = new ArrayList<Document>();
list1.add("90:200");
list1.add("350:400");
list1.add("560:700");

for (String time : list1) {
    String[] updatedAtt = time.split(":");

    andQueryList.add(new Document("$and", Arrays.asList(new Document("updated_at", new Document("$gte", Long.parseLong(updatedAtt[0]))),
                new Document("updated_at", new Document("$lte", Long.parseLong(updatedAtt[1]))))));
}
query.put("$or", andQueryList);
```

The query output is as follows (equivalent of Mongo Query)

> Document{{$or=[Document{{$and=[Document{{updated_at=Document{{$gte=90}}}},
>   Document{{updated_at=Document{{$lte=200}}}}]}},
>   Document{{$and=[Document{{updated_at=Document{{$gte=350}}}},
>   Document{{updated_at=Document{{$lte=400}}}}]}},
>   Document{{$and=[Document{{updated_at=Document{{$gte=560}}}},
>   Document{{updated_at=Document{{$lte=700}}}}]}}]}}

Comment: @Roshan Quadras But it now gives me last value. As it is overriding the last value into the document. Document{{ $or=Document{{$and=[Document{{updated_at=Document{{$gte=560}}}}, Document{{updated_at=Document{{$lte=700}}}}]}}}}

Comment: @Kamini ​The andQuery reference was pointing to the last value as we are recreating list object inside for loop. I have updated the query snippet, which will print the expected result.